# Enable Remember me option in laravel fortify

Tags: laravel, fortify

So, I've just built my website authentication system using laravel fortify, however, I'm finding a problem on how to implement the remember me option. I could use some help. if there's a built-in method in fortify it would be even better.

I am using laravel 8 and fortify 1.6

Answer (score 6):

According to this issue https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/17

Taylor suggests that you shouldn't use the Auth::attempt method in Fortify::authenticateUsing method as it will essentially be logging in twice.

You should use Auth::validate.

Btw, if you have an input (checkbox) named "remember" it will still be passed along.

Hope this helps someone, because I spent hours trying to get to the bottom of how to use remember with Fortify::authenticateUsing.

Comment: Would you mind showing us your code with Fortify::authenticateUsing? Where did you put it? I haven't been able to find good docs on this. It's like a very essential and common functionality that's been left out of the docs, not sure why.

Comment: I can't make this work. Help?

Comment: For anyone wondering how exactly to implement it. I've implemented it in Laravel and Vuejs like this  `<input type="checkbox" v-model="fields.remember" id="remember" />`.

Answer (score 2):

So, after surfing in the whole fortify assets xD, I found that it accepts a second parameter in the attempt method which is rememberMe option as a "remember" post data name. So u just have to set the remember me checkbox name to "remember" and its gonna work like magic.

Comment: "magic", this word in programming really scares me

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#remembering-users